# BYTEA retrieval via Fat Free Framework SQL data mapper

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, orm, fat-free-framework

I am trying to retrieve stored binary data (`bytea`) from a PostgreSQL database using the `\DB\SQL\Mapper` in the Fat Free Framework.

However for some reason I can't seem to get anything other than a "Resource ID" string. For example.

```
    // Establish database communication
    $this->db = new \DB\SQL(
        $f3->get("database.type") .
        ":host=" . $f3->get("database.host") .
        ";port=" . $f3->get("database.port") .
        ";dbname=" . $f3->get("database.name"),
        $f3->get("database.user"),
        $f3->get("database.password"),
        array(
            \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE,
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );

    // Firmware Object-Relational-Mapper
    $this->firmware = new \DB\SQL\Mapper(
        $this->db,
        "firmware"
    );

    // Selection parameters 
    $this->select = array(
          "id=:id",
          ":id" => array(
              $f3->get("PARAMS.id"),
              \PDO::PARAM_INT
          )
    );

    // Map to record
    $this->firmware->load($this->select);

    // Error: expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
    // $this->firmware->binary is "Resource id #23"
    fpassthru($this->firmware->binary);
```

However if I execute a prepared statement against the `\DB\SQL` PDO class I can retrieve the binary data without issue. i.e.

```
    $record = $this->db->exec(
        'SELECT "binary" FROM "firmware" WHERE id=?',
         $f3->get("PARAMS.id")
    );

    fpassthru($record[0]['binary']); //spits out the binary data
```

So my question is; is there a way to retrieve the binary data from the table whilst still using the ORM in Fat Free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because of the type conversion, which is applied [here](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/master/db/sql/mapper.php#L280-L283).
The ORM was probably not able to find the correct pdo type for your binary field in PostgreSQL.

You can try to overwrite it like this:

```
$this->firmware = new \DB\SQL\Mapper(
   $this->db,
   "firmware"
);       
$schema = $this->firmware->schema();
$schema['binary']['pdo_type'] = \PDO::PARAM_LOB;
$this->firmware->schema($schema);
```

It could be that you also need to adjust the [db->value method](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/master/db/sql.php#L105) and add default case which just returns what went into, so the value is passed through `return $val`.

Comment: Very good, overriding the schema and adding a case to the switch solved it. Although rather than a default case I added `case \PDO::PARAM_LOB: return $val;`

Comment: Just to add I also amended https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/master/db/sql.php#L86 .i.e. `case 'bytea' : return \PDO::PARAM_LOB;`